# Firebase not working with Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create an app using Cordova and Firebase.

I started by doing a simple test of reading or writing to my Firebase database. Yet nothing happens, except Firebase shows that the downloaded data is going up but no connections or anything.

I am able to connect to other online API's and services, so I know it's not an issue with my app connecting to the internet.

I even set the database permissions to public so anyone could read/write.

I have tried multiple cordova firebase plugins, but nothing is working.

I have followed all the tutorials and looked at examples, so my config is setup properly as well.

Here is my database outline:

[image: Database outline]

Here is some of my code:

Initialization:

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "<api-key>",
    authDomain: "<something>.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://<something>.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "<something>.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "<sender-id>"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Attempting to query the database (called when a button is clicked):

```
function alertData(){
return firebase.database().ref('/articles/0').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  var dat = snapshot.val().content;
  alert(dat);
});
}
```

Yet absolutely nothing happens.

Anybody know how to fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Please add some code related to the issue so we can analyze your problem easier

Comment: I added what the database looks like and a code snippet.

Comment: Hello, did you succeed in fixing your problem ? I runned into some strange behaviours with firebase in my cordova app so I'm interested with your experience on the matter. :)

Comment: @adz5A I did not unfortunately :( No error messages or anything, it just doesn't work. However when running as a website, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Using Firebase in Cordova is the same as using that on any Web page. **No extra plugin required**.

Just remember following points:

1. Don't forget to load firebase script files through CDN:

   ```
   <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
   <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.3/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
   ```
2. First load cordova.js then initialize your app and then use index.js.